# Azure Function: Event Grid Output Binding Throwing InvalidOperationException: 'Can't convert from type 'Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.EventGridEvent

Tags: f#, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to build an Azure Function in F# with an Event Grid output binding. The code I have builds fine, but whenever I try and run it, I get the runtime exception: InvalidOperationException: 'Can't convert from type 'Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.EventGridEvent.

This is my code (note, I'm not currently using the outputEvents argument in the function, as I first wanted to make sure I could run the function before adding events to it):

```
[<FunctionName("EventListener")>]
let run ([<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)>]req: HttpRequest)
        ([<EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "TopicEndpoint", TopicKeySetting = "TopicKey")>]outputEvents: IAsyncCollector<EventGridEvent>)
        (log: ILogger) =
    async {
        log.LogInformation("F# HTTP trigger function processed a request.")

        let nameOpt = 
            if req.Query.ContainsKey(Name) then
                Some(req.Query.[Name].[0])
            else
                None

        use stream = new StreamReader(req.Body)
        let! reqBody = stream.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

        let data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NameContainer>(reqBody)

        let name =
            match nameOpt with
            | Some n -> n
            | None ->
               match data with
               | null -> ""
               | nc -> nc.Name
        
        let responseMessage =             
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) then
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            else
                "Hello, " +  name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."

        return OkObjectResult(responseMessage) :> IActionResult
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo we can use to reproduce what you're seeing, instead of having to build it from scratch?

Comment: Can you also share what version of the extension you are using?

Comment: Any Update to the issue?

Comment: Pls check this. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/477